# How to implement a Facebook-like previewer

Tags: php, facebook, thumbnails, web-scraping, preview

I was looking at how Facebook makes external websites previews given on a URL shared by the user. The result is not just a thumbnail but actual text, an embedded video or an image depending on the link given. For example, if you post a link from a Wikipedia article, it displays text. If you post the link of a video from Dailymotion, it embeds it.
Is there a PHP/Javascript-Ajax approach to accomplish this? Any specific library for this purpose?

If there isn't, what's the best way server-side (in PHP if possible) solution for web scraping and displaying a thumbnail preview?

Comment: They have specific websites flagged for custom previews (think YouTube or other video sites), but otherwise it simply reads the meta description, title, and looks for images on the page (not in css). This is if there is not any specific facebook markup.

Comment: There is Facebook specific markup, their `og` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does this by looking for [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). In the case of embedded videos, it's looking for the `og:video` tag.

If there aren't OG tags, it'll make a best guess.